# How can I have a alert message in a div inside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script and it sends out an alert message. All I want is to put the alert message in a div inside the form. Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var registered=false

function ExamineRegistration()
{
var email =document.regform.email.value;
var emailcheck= email.indexOf("@")
var emailcheck2= email.indexOf(".")
var password = document.regform.pass.value;
var passcheck = password.charAt(0)
var message_out = "Errors: "

if(email=="" || password==""){
message_out = message_out+"All boxes should be filled in, "
}

if(emailcheck==-1 || emailcheck2==-1)
{
message_out = message_out+"email must contain @ and ., "
}

if(password!=password)
{
message_out=message_out+"password must match"
}

if(message_out == "Errors: ") {
    message_out = "You have successfully been logged in!"
    registered=true
}

alert(message_out);
}
--> This function helps the user first to register and than to enter the site.
function Checkreg() {
if (registered ==true) {
location.replace("http://www.google.com")
}
else alert("Please Login to proceed")
}
</script>
```

I have a form. I just want the alert message to appear inside the form at the top. I just dont know how to display the alert message inside the form instead of a pop up.

Comment: You cannot reposition the native `alert()` window. You will have to create your own user interface for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
function customAlert(message){
    $('#divId').html(message);
}

..
..
customAlert('Danger! aliens attacking us!')
```

You can also cache the div element.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.realAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {document.getElementById('my_div_id').innerHTML = msg;}

.... some code with redirected alerts ....

// restoring alert
window.alert = window.realAlert;
```

Comment: Ohhh, no! don't override window properties!

Comment: @gdoron - This is a risky solution, but to meet the requirements it would work, only if this is the only place where an alert will be shown.  But, it is a creative solution.

Comment: @JamesBlack. Yes it's creative all right but risky and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Modified answer to be less risky :)

Comment: I really don't understand why you're trying so much to override the `alert` function, instead of writing a new one.

Comment: If the script is external part of some API it is not always possible to modify it to use customAlert(), of course it is better not to change what is defined, but extend and use customised functions/methods.